# Как сделать, чтобы собранный JAR видел .xls файл?

Tags: java, excel, jar, xls, apache-poi

День добрый.
Программа написана с помощью JavaFX. При нажатии button программа считывает данные с .xls файла. Когда запускаю код с IntelliJ IDEA все работает. Но когда собираю JAR файл и запускаю его, при нажатии кнопки, данные из .xls файла не читаются. 
JAR собран через Build Artifacts, а не через Maven

```
File f1 = new File("C:\\2.xls");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f1);
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

int length=0;
int dat=0;
float tick=0;
boolean kik=true;
int y=1;

 while (kik){ try{
        length = (int) wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(y).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
    }catch (Exception e){kik=false;}
        try {dat = (int) wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(y).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
        tick = (float) wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(y).getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
}catch (Exception e){}
y++;}
```

библиотеки:
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
poi-3.17.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
poi-examples-3.17.jar
poi-excelant-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку_ и _минимальный код для её воспроизведения_ **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы **без явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Что значит перестаёт читать? Подробнее опишите проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась заменой

```
File f1 = new File("C:\\2.xls");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f1);
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

на

```
InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/2.xls"); 
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

при этом сначала файл 2.xls занес в classpath

Решение нашел здесь https://stackoverflow.com/q/20389255/8713992